# Remap Super+arrow key to home/end

Tags: linux, keyboard, remapping

A lot of new ultra books are coming without home/end/pageup/pagedown keys. I would like to remap the "windows key (super) + arrow key" to these missing keys.

What is the best way to go about doing this? It seems that xev is reporting pressing the Super key as its own keypress, rather than a modifier to other keys.

Comment: If you use X, have a look at `xmodmap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a combination of xdotool and xbindkeys, with a .xbindkeysrc like:

```
"xdotool key Next"
  Mod4 + Down

"xdotool key Prior"
  Mod4 + Up
```

(on my system windows key is bound to Hyper_L = Mod4)

Another (very cool) option if you don't mind using the mouse could be to use gestures. For instance on my netbook the End key is a pain to use (Fn+Pagedown, and hard to reach). I installed easystroke and set it up so i can just make a "V" like gesture and it sends End. For Pagedown, it's a down-up "|" gesture (begins to feel a lot like an iphone!)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [my reply to a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65434/map-superleftright-to-home-end/65923#65923).

It defines a type SUPER_LEVEL_2 that can be used to define (in level 2, aka "shift", position) what other keys will send when pressed with "Super".

If you want to use another modifier than Super you just need to adapt
(but check if there isn't already a type for it)

Answer (score -1):

This is from `xmodmap` documentation.

> keycode NUMBER = KEYSYMNAME ...
>
> ```
>            The  list  of  keysyms  is assigned to the indicated keycode
>            (which may be specified in decimal, hex or octal and can  be
>            determined by running the xev program).  Up to eight keysyms
>            may be attached to a key, however the last four are not used
>            in  any  major X server implementation.  The first keysym is
>            used when no modifier key is  pressed  in  conjunction  with
>            this  key,  the  second  with  Shift,  the  third  when  the
>            Mode_switch key is used with this key and  the  fourth  when
>            both the Mode_switch and Shift keys are used.
> ```